# errno22 with pip3 on wsl

Tags: python-3.x, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install a local python package I made. However when I run the command

```
pip3 install .
```

i get this error :

```
shutil.Error: [('/mnt/c/Users/Marco/OneDrive - 
UNED/05_SCRIPT_DEV/05_LP_GEOM_PLOTTER/plotlp/plotlp', '/tmp/pip-4y8smgxg- 
build/plotlp', "[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/tmp/pip-4y8smgxg- 
build/plotlp'"), ('/mnt/c/Users/Marco/OneDrive - 
UNED/05_SCRIPT_DEV/05_LP_GEOM_PLOTTER/plotlp', '/tmp/pip-4y8smgxg-build', " 
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: '/tmp/pip-4y8smgxg-build'")]
```

This is quite confusing, considering that if I use pip for python2.7 for this same task it works as a charm!

My setup is Ubuntu 18 on WSL (windows). The python version I am trying to use is 3.5. 
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: have you tried using python3.7 -m pip

Comment: yep, same error..